# Stack Exchange - Comment converts to answer if page changes focus

Tags: bug, android-app

As I have had to do multiple times (vote for my answer to be "seen by moderators" to delete them), I cannot help but think that when I change the active page on the app when composing a reply and then go back (seems to apply also for switching away and then back to the app) that my comment I am composing is now in "compose an answer" mode... or it just makes an answer instead of a comment.

I don't know if it is really my mistake (because the button to answer is extremely near the add comment button) or if I really am correct like I'm guessing.

Comment: By page do you mean switching apps?

Comment: switching "pages" within the app, but also using the native Android features to switch from the Stack Exchange app to something else and then back.

Comment: If you still don't understand by "pages", think like the Stack Exchange app is a somewhat modified web browser app.

Comment: Yeah I think I get you, but when I use the app and start writing a comment and go back to another page in the app, the partial comment doesn't save when I get back.... I think I'm misunderstanding the whole question :/

Comment: I navigate to a new page, then I go back in the app to it. (Also, going back seems to be a pain for me because when I search tags, select a tag, then look at a question, going back jumps to the tag listing... back is bugged...)

Comment: My issue is I am going forward to a notification that popped up... then I go back and get the issue

Comment: Mind posting screenshots and also your Android version? I've encountered some oddities when composing comments, but primarily they just lose track of the post and refuse to submit; haven't seen them convert to an answer.